# print the response json with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a problem, when I want to print the response json through a message alert. 
This is my script :

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {          
        "Accept" : "application/json",         
        "Content-Type": "application/json"   
      },
    url: "http://192.168.1.1:8000",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonString),
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      $('#response').html(xhr); 
  },
  cache: false,
  success: function(xhr){
    alert(console.log(xhr));
 }
```

});

This is my message can be.
 **"undefined"**

This response data from the console
[image]

Comment: console.log() doesn't have a return value ...

Comment: use either `console.log(xhr)` or `alert(xhr)`

Comment: `console.log()` doesn't return anything (meaning it returns `undefined`) and you're trying to alert value returned by `consolelog`

Comment: `success: function(xhr){
    console.log(xhr);
    alert(JSON.stringify(xhr));
 }`

Comment: you should mention datatype:"json" in ajax

Comment: @AdityaParab I want to test through alerts.
If this is successful I want to display it in the html element.

Comment: @SitiRahmah just use the `alert(xhr)`  because `console.log(xhr)` is not returning anything to put in alert.

Comment: Okay. But be aware that alert will show you `[object Object]`. You may wanna try `alert(JSON.stringify(xhr))`

Comment: already however that appears [object Object] @AdityaParab

Comment: @SitiRahmah:Use `alert(JSON.stringify(xhr))` . Although I'm not sure why you'd use alert for debugging. `console.log` is better suited for what you're trying to do.

Comment: @AdityaParab Thank you it's been successful, now I just display it with the html element, can give me references tutorial? :)

Comment: @SitiRahmah: I'm not sure how you want it displayed on the UI. So it's hard to point out proper tutorial. But for now, you can just create a div in your html `<div id="result"></div>` and in your success callback (where you have alert), write `$('#result').text(JSON.stringify(xhr));`

Comment: @SitiRahmah don't test using `alert()`. It coerces data types which is not what you want when debugging. I strongly suggest you use `console.log()` or `console.dir`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this

```
alert(xhr);
```

OR

```
alert(JSON.stringify(xhr));
```

complete code is as follows

```
$.ajax({
        headers: {          
            "Accept" : "application/json",         
            "Content-Type": "application/json"   
          },
        url: "http://192.168.1.1:8000",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(jsonString),
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          $('#response').html(xhr); 
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function(xhr){
        alert(JSON.stringify(xhr));
     }

    });
```